# ASP.NET Web Forms Modal Form

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to duplicate/emulate the following type of form (that I see in some web sites). 
On Log In form when user clicks on Forgot Password link a modal form appears (right over the Log In Form) that has a instructions text on the top and a text box for user to enter his/her email.
Does this type of Modal "Forget Password" form has to be created as just another ASP.NET web form?  Or there is another approach?

Comment: What you should consider is that this is happening on the client. So what you want can be accomplished with CSS and JavaScript. There are lots of libraries such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) that make it a cinch to create a dialog window. It's not clear to me what exactly you mean by "just another ASP.NET web form." Perhaps you should explain what you mean by that.

Comment: @mason  The Forgot Password form has to email to the user his/her password. Therefore I see the need for the Submit_click() method. And I don't know if such a Submit_click() method can be done without creating an ASP.NET web form. And I don't know if the "dialog window" you suggest can have the functionality to email. Hopefully this clarifies what I meant.  Thank you.

Comment: So create a `Submit_Click()` method to handle your button's click event. But your button inside the modal dialog, and put the markup for the modal dialog on your .aspx or .master page. It's not too hard. (But personally I'd steer away from using postbacks and call a Web API function with AJAX rather than requiring the whole form to submit).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can accomplish this:

Create a button that opens the Modal and on the button click command add this to the code behind:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ModalPopup", "ModalPopup()", true);
```

^ this will launch the following code.

```
 <div id = modalpopup style="display:none;">
 <asp:Table runat = "server">
 <asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right">Textbox:</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
                 <asp:Table runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            // textbox here
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                     </asp:Table>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>     
 </asp:Table>
          <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddTransaction" Style="display: none" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnAddModalTransaction_Click" ValidationGroup="Transaction" CausesValidation="true" />
          <asp:Button ID="btnCancelAddTransaction" runat="server" Style="display: none" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancelAddTransaction_Click" CausesValidation="false" />

 </div>
```

//--------------- Javascript modal popup

```
          function ModalPopup() {
        $("#modalpopup ").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 800,
            appendTo: "form",
            open: function () {


                // The two lines below are 2 different ways to ensure the 
                // background is completely grayed out if the modal is larger
                // then the page. The first was chosen so that the scroll
                // bars are not disabled.
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'fixed');
                //$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                $(this).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {                                        
                   $("[id*=btnAddTransaction]").click();                             
                },

                "Cancel": function () {                        
                    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel ?")) {
                        $("[id*=btnCancelAddTransaction]").click();                            
                    }
                }
            },
            close: function (ev, ui) {
                $(this).remove();                  
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'absolute');
            }
        });
```

Your site master should include references to these local scripts (inside your script folder): 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will try your suggestions

Comment: No problem, if it suits your needs please remember to checkmark this solution. Thank you.

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention that this requires jQuery UI, you may want to show how to embed the references to the CDN hosted version of it.

Comment: Good point. 

add this to your sitemaster script section: 

- <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a modal popup without using ajax/javascript try this method that only uses html & css: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

I modifed the modal div to hook up to a method in code-behind. You can do the same to make it send an email or do whatever else you like. Just remove the opacity attribute in css and set the modal div default visibility to visible=false, as shown below.

CSS:

```
</style>    
    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    }
    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        margin-left:20%;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }
    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }
    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpenModal" runat="server" Text="Open Modal Window" OnClick="btnOpenModal_Click" />
<br />
<div id="divModal" runat="server" class ="modalDialog" visible="false">
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnModalClose" runat="server"  CssClass="close" Text="X" OnClick="CloseModal" />
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using CSS3.</p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnEmail" runat="server" Text="Send Email" Onclick="SendEmail" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="CloseModal" />
    </div>
</div>
```

C# Code behind:

```
protected void btnOpenModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divModal.Visible = true;
}
protected void CloseModal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divModal.Visible = false;
}
protected void btnEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //put your code here that sends an email
}
```